# How to read set of dicom images into one tensor using the tensorflow data API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am attempting to build a regression model in tensorflow using dicom images and an associated value for each set of dicom images. As part of this my data is set up with 20 files in each folder, where each folder represents an individual patient's data sample, and each image represents a channel of our overall 20 channel sample:.
:

```
patient_1/
        p1_image1.dcm
        ...
        p1_image20.dcm

patient_2/
        p2_image1.dcm
        ...
        p2_image20.dcm
```

The end goal is to have each set of images in one tensor, with dimensions [H,W,20] where H and W are the height and width of the individual dicom images.

Because I have a lot of data, and I can't read them all into memory at once, I have been trying to read them in using tensorflow's data api for building data pipelines. I have not had much luck with this, as reading these images, then concatenating them into one tensor for each patient has proved to be very tricky.

Here is a sample of what I have been trying to do:

```
import pydicom
import tensorflow as tf
def tf_parse_filename(folder_name):

    def read_files(folder_path):
    
        print(folder_path)        
        images = []
        for filename in folder_path:
        
            file_string = tf.strings.as_string(filename)
            print(file_string)            
            read_image = pydicom.dcmread(file_string.numpy()).pixel_array/4095.0
            images.append(read_image)

        return tf.stack(images)

    x = tf.py_function(read_files, [folder_name], [tf.float32])
    return x

folder_paths = ["0000001_123_2_0", "0000002_123_2_0", "0000003_123_2_0"]
values = ["0.1", "4.4", "3.2"]
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(folder_paths)
train_ds = train_ds.map(tf_parse_filename, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

But I have been getting an error when calling file_string.numpy() which states

```
Value for attr 'T' of string is not in the list of allowed values: float, double, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, half, uint32, uint64, complex64, complex128, bool, variant
```

This is despite me calling tf.strings.as_string in the code before passing it to the pydicom read. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or how to do this pipeline read more properly?